# DeepFace analyze function rises serialization issue

Tags: python, json, deepface

i would like to use deepface algorithm for detection human's emotion from the image, here is my code :

```
import  cv2
from deepface import DeepFace
import numpy as np
import json
image =cv2.imread('emotion.jpg')
#json.dumps(image)
analyze =DeepFace.analyze(image,actions='emotions',enforce_detection=False)
print(analyze)
```

but when i have  run the code, got the following error

```
C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Project\emotion_detection.py 
Action: e:   0%|          | 0/8 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Project\emotion_detection.py", line 7, in <module>
    analyze =DeepFace.analyze(image,actions=('emotions'),enforce_detection=False)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AI_Project\venv\lib\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py", line 452, in analyze
    resp_obj["region"][parameter] = int(region[i]) #int cast is for the exception - object of type 'float32' is not JSON serializable
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i have searched a lot about this problem, for instance  try the following  code

```
json.dumps(image)
```

but when i run, got :

```
TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable
```

please  tell me is there any solution? or it is just  deepface's bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass the image directly. No need to read with opencv & then pass to [Deepface.analyze](https://github.com/serengil/deepface). Read documentaion clearly.

```
backends = ['opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib', 'mtcnn', 'retinaface', 'mediapipe']
analyze = DeepFace.analyze(img_path = 'emotion.jpg', detector_backend =backends[4])
print(analyze)
```

Comment: then i have question :  why  backends=[4]?

Comment: Here is the docs for the method: https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/deepface/DeepFace.py#L268

Comment: Deepace supports multiple backends...You can try anything like `backends[0]` , `backends[1]`.....Upto `backends[5]`...`backends[4]` is mtcnn if you go all the way down you can see accuracies of each backends...mtcnn has more accuracy...so auother used `backends[4]` for all examples...If results are not right then change other backends

Comment: yes but from the list of backends fourth one is  retinface , is not it?

Comment: @Machine_Learning List index starts from zero 0th elemnt is opencv, 1st elemnt is ssd....

Comment: yes that's why backends = ['opencv', 'ssd', 'dlib', 'mtcnn', 'retinaface', 'mediapipe'],backends[0] is opencv, backends[1] is ssd, backends[2] is dlib, backends[3] is mtcnn  and  backends[4] is retinface

Comment: ahh sorry..`backends[4]` is retinface

Comment: but, Yes...if your results are not right feel to try other backends...When I was working with deepface default `backends[4]` given me most of the results but, sometimes it fails when images are blurry or too much over cropped...in that cases I use to shift to `backends[0]` -Which also works fine

Comment: dont  worry sir, everything is great, wish you  good night